# How to sort a dataframe by its values horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

Say you have the following dataframe:

```
Columns                    X        Y          Z
Index_Col                                                     
A                        1.0      3.0        2.0
B                        1.0      3.0        2.0
C                        1.0      3.0        2.0
```

How do you sort the values horizontally so that it becomes:

```
Columns                    Y        Z          X
Index_Col                                                     
A                        3.0      2.0        1.0
B                        3.0      2.0        1.0
C                        3.0      2.0        1.0
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140223/how-to-sort-data-frame-by-column-values

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. sort the `values` of the dataframe ascendingly

   df.values.sort()
2. reverse its order

   df[df.columns][::-1]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
df.sort_values(by = 'row_name', axis = 1)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-rows-or-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values/